# Создать несколько проектов на одном сервере

Tags: apache, php, linux

У меня на Linux Ubuntu стоит сервер апач.
Пока я делаю один сайт, но нужно сделать еще несколько.

Что мне сделать чтобы я мог из адресной строки переходить на нужный мне сайт?
сейчас я ввожу http://localhost/ и перехожу на один проект, а надо например http://new_project/ чтобы перейти на другой на том же компе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если устанавливали апач через apt-get(aptitude) тогда идем в папку /etc/apache2 ищем файл httpd-vhosts.conf у меня он в папке conf/extra/ но я собирал руками, так что у вас может отличаться. прописываем новый виртуальный хост

<virtualhost my.new=""> 
  ServerName my.new
  ServerAdmin admin@my.new
  DocumentRoot /var/www/my.new/
</virtualhost>

это все из под рута делать надо

по умолчанию папка апача помоему тут /var/www/ проверьте как у вас ... 
создаем там папку для нового проекта.

потом правим из под рута /etc/hosts и добавляем туда строку 
127.0.0.1 my.new

перезагружаем апач

sudo /etc/apache2/apachectl restart

новый хост будет доступен по адресу http://my.new

Comment: значит, как я сделал:
файл httpd-vhosts.conf не помог, зато помогли изменения для файла httpd.conf и изменения в /etc/hosts

"NameVirtualHost localhost

<VirtualHost example1>
    ServerName example1
    ServerAdmin email@example1
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost example2>
    ServerName example2
    ServerAdmin email@example2
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example2
</VirtualHost>"

Comment: в папках example1 и example2 хранятся разные проекты. если кому нужны дополнительные примочки и прибамбасы к серверу, действительно, читайте как настраивать VirtualHost.

Answer (score 1):

читать про VirtualHost

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант (я так делаю) - в папке локалхост создавать папки с проектами, например

**http://localhost/site1/**

**http://localhost/site2/**

etc.

Comment: угу и везде вместо $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] пишите $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/site1/', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/site2/' etc? ^^<br>